# How can pte's be accessed through ring 0 virtual memory?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, virtual-address-space, page-tables

Can somebody point me to code or some resource on how the kernel maps process page tables to kernel space?

How does this work on 32 bit and 64 bit (on x86 and x86_64 processors) ?
How does the kernel setup page tables of process and kernel to be accessed through kernel virtual addresses ?

There seems to be a chicken and egg problem. You need a virtual address in the kernel to access a physical page, but you need a page table entry for this , which is setup using virtual address to access a physical page.

Answer (score 0):

Paging is not enabled on initial entry into protected mode: the system initially operates with a direct mapping of RAM. In this mode, the kernel sets up initial page table entries and any other necessary information, then enables paging.

Cite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Protected_mode